# django: order of post_syncdb signals

Tags: python, django

I followed the instructions and created my post_syncdb signal inside `app/management/__init__.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_syncdb
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
import payment.models as payModels


def initialization(sender, **kwargs):
    """ initialization when appliation starts """
    agents = Group.objects.get(name = "agents")
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    if not agents.permissions.filter(codename="can_buy_package").exists():
        perm = Permission.objects.get(codename="can_buy_package")
        agents.permissions.add(perm)

post_syncdb.connect(initialization, sender= payModels)
```

the signal runs, but using the python debugger there, it seems at that particular time no permissions, even the standard ones were created for my models inside the same app.

can someone advise?

-----------------------**updated**---------------------------

After Chris's comments, I took a look at the dispatcher class and inserted debug messages into the related files to understand more.

Essentially, in my app (which was further down the list in `INSTALLED_APPS` than `contenttype` and `auth` ) its `post_syncdb` handlers were added to the signal first. Turns out because during setup, Django looks for custom commands to install inside the the app's management/commands folder, signal handlers inside my management/**init**.py was executed.

I then tried to put the `post_syncdb.connect` inside my `models.py`. Running a trace shows that using haystack might also run into similar issue

> (,
>   '/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/property/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py',
>   35, 'import_module', ['    **import**(name)\n    '], 0), (,
>   '/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/property/lib/python2.6/site-packages/haystack/**init**.py',
>   121, 'autodiscove    r', ['
>   importlib.import_module("%s.search_indexes" % app)\n'], 0), (, '/Users/foo/Documents/workspace/prop
>   erty_buyer/haystack_sites.py', 2, '',
>   ['haystack.autodiscover()\n'], 0), (,
>   '/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/prop
>   erty/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py', 35,
>   'import_module', ['    **import**(name)\n'], 0), (, '/Us
>   ers/foo/.virtualenvs/property/lib/python2.6/site-packages/haystack/**init**.py',
>   151, 'handle_registrations', ['    search_sites_conf = importlib
>   .import_module(settings.HAYSTACK_SITECONF)\n'], 0), (,
>   '/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/property/lib/python2.6/site-packa
>   ges/haystack/**init**.py', 154, '',
>   ['handle_registrations()\n'], 0), (,
>   '/Users/foo/.virtualenvs/propert
>   y/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py', 35,
>   'import_module', ['    **import**(name)\n'], 0),

Hope this is useful for folks whose handlers are order dependent and run into similar cases

Comment: You code says if `can_buy_package` *doesn't* exist, then fetch it from the database. That doesn't make any sense. It should just be `if`, rather than `if not`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, hmm even so, running Permission.objects.get(codename="can_buy_package") or Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label="payment") doesn't return me any results.. any idea if it is a race condition between this signal and auth?

Comment: Did you actually solve the problem? I am having a simmilar issue but my handlers are already in the models.py

Comment: HI circus, I have forgotten about it but i believe i did not really solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things to note. First, the `post_syncdb` signal is sent after each app is synced, so it's sent once for each app, not just once at the end. Second, there appears to be an inherent and stable order to which handlers are applied when, but it's not controllable.

To elaborate on the second point, I've spent the better part of 30 minutes just staring at `auth`'s permissions `post_syncdb` handler, and I can't see anything that actually ensures that it comes after the same handler for `contenttypes`. Yet, nevertheless, it uses `ContentType` freely, confident that everything is ready to go. My only conclusion is that the order of the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` matters, and it would appear that apps later in the list  have their handlers processed before apps sooner in the list. My only conclusion is that `auth` benefits from starting with the letter `A`, and that few people would move it below `contenttypes` in the list as a result.

That would also mean that your app, which is inevitably defined after `contenttypes` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, has its signal handlers run *before* those of `contenttypes`, and there's your problem. It's not so much a race condition as it just always ahead of `contenttypes`.

You could, I suppose, move your app up in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but that might cause other unforeseen issues. You could also try changing the `sender` attribute to a different models file, perhaps even `contenttypes`, and maybe that might give it enough time to pop.

Comment: that is strange, because i have another app 'acc' with the same signal that checks for contenttype in my acc.models, and it is below contenttype in the INSTALLED_APPS and it works

Comment: Essentially, you are correct to say that the order of INSTALLED_APPS matters. In addition, I've also added some observations which might be useful ...